# how to show alert errors during validation of unique field in modal form using laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm working with Laravel and I'm new there.
I have a modal form in currencies view everything is ok but I have a problem that when I click on save button and the "CurrencyName" is duplicate I got an alert but I got that alert after closing the modal form and get back to "currencies" page.

the following code in "currencies" view page:

```
 <div class="d-flex my-xl-auto right-content">
        <a class="modal-effect btn-block" data-effect="effect-scale" data-toggle="modal" href="#modaldemo8">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-icon ml-2">
                <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
<div class="modal" id="modaldemo8" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-content-demo">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title">new</h6><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="needs-validation was-validated" action="{{ route('currencies.store') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row row-sm">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="txtcurrencytype" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">type</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcurrencytype" name="txtcurrencytype" value="forg" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="txtcurrencyname" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">currency name</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcurrencyname" name="CurrencyName" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="txtcurrencyprice1" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">price1</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtcurrencyprice1" name="txtcurrencyprice1" step="any" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="txtcurrencyprice2" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">price2</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtcurrencyprice2" name="txtcurrencyprice2" step="any" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Errors -->
                            @if ($errors->any())
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            @endif
                            <!-- Errors -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn ripple btn-primary" type="submit">save</button>
                        <button class="btn ripple btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate(
            [
                'CurrencyName' => ['unique:tblcurrencies', 'max:50']
            ],
            [
                'CurrencyName.unique' => 'err1!',
                'CurrencyName.max' => 'err2!'
            ]
        );

        Currency::create(
            [
                'CurrencyRef' => Helper::GetNewRef(),
                'CurrencyName' => $request['CurrencyName'],
                'CurrencyPrice1' => $request['txtcurrencyprice1'],
                'CurrencyPrice2' => $request['txtcurrencyprice2'],
                'CurrentUser' => auth()->id()
            ]
        );
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

what I need is when I click on Save button (if there are any errors I want to display the alert in the modal form without closing the modal form)

Comment: any answers please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, that question was here for 10 days without any answer! I am new in web development but I tried many solutions and finally I got it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#xform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var formData = $(this).serialize(); 
        
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) {
                location.reload(); 
            },                
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
                if (errors) {
                    $('#errs').empty();
                    $.each(errors, function(key, value) {
                        $('#errs').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                    });
                    $('#errs').show();

                    if (!$('#modaldemo8').hasClass('show')) {
                        $('#modaldemo8').modal('show');
                    }
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

and you should delete the following part:

```
        <!-- Errors -->
                        @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        <!-- Errors -->
```